# How to read GTFS Real-time feed using Python

Tags: python-3.x, python-requests, httprequest, protocol-buffers, gtfs

This is not a repeat question. I am desgning a routing algorithm that works in realtime. I know all about GTFS static feed but cant figure out my cities realtime. I want to understand how to parse and GTFS realtime feed using Python.

Link to Realtime set of my city is https://opendata.iiitd.edu.in/data/realtime/

I know a little about Protocol buffers and request library. Documentaion does not give the link to which API request should be placed. 
What is the Url for this set which goes into requests.get?

Answer (score 1):

There is a python library called gtfs_realtime_pb2, which can be used to parse the response of a request to the realtime feed and receive usefull output.
The main page for this library is [here](https://github.com/MobilityData/gtfs-realtime-bindings). There are also binding for other languages.

The main workflow is to initialize the

`feed = gtfs_realtime_pb2.FeedMessage()`

get the response from the feed with the package requests

`response = requests.get(<url>, allow-redirects = True)`
and parse it for example:
  `feed.ParseFromString(response.content)`

`feed.entity[int]`